# With semantic-release how can I view the release note in dry run without publishing rights?

Tags: node.js, semantic-release

Using semantic-release I want to verify my commit message can render proper release notes, and I have no publishing rights, how do I do it?

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the documents:

https://github.com/semantic-release/semantic-release/blob/master/docs/usage/configuration.md#configuration

There is a dry flag command option -d.  Give that a shot.